# `__init__()` always raises error

Tags: python, oop, subclass

So, I have defined the following class which should resemble a [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function). However, its logic seems broken and it will raise `SUM_ERROR` every time I try to initialize a new object.

```
class ProbabilityMass(dict):

  class InvalidEntries(Exception):
    pass

  SUM_ERROR = InvalidEntries("all values must add upto '1'")
  VAL_ERROR = InvalidEntries("negative values are not allowed")

  def __init__(self, pm):
    dict.__init__(pm)
    # Input requirements
    if not self.sumsUptoOne():
      raise ProbabilityMass.SUM_ERROR
    if not self.isNonnegative():
      raise ProbabilityMass.VAL_ERROR

  def isNonnegative(self):
    return all(d < 0 for d in self.values())

  def sumsUptoOne(self):
    return sum(self.values()) == 1
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Canonical syntax. `q = ProbabilityMass({...})`

Comment: `print(sum(self.values()))`. My guess is that you have floating point issues and need to only require that the sum is very close to 1.

Comment: Using your code, and giving it a dict as you initialize it, `self.values()` is an empty list, as is `self.keys()`

Comment: You also want `d > 0` instead of `d < 0` to test that the values are non-negative

Comment: You might consider doing the checks from `ProbabilityMass.__new__` instead; there is no point in creating a new object if you're going to raise an error anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `dict.__init__()` does not initialize the class. The correct call to `super` should look like this:

```
def __init__(self, pm):
    super(ProbabilityMass, self).__init__(pm)
    # Input requirements
    ...
```

As a side note, your `isNonnegative()` method is also incorrect. Change it to:

```
def isNonnegative(self):
    return all(d >= 0 for d in self.values())
```

Comment: Ops, it's just a typo; it originally was `any(...)`

Comment: @Neysofu It would still be incorrect. Maybe you meant `return not any(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when `dict.__init__()` is called, it is because you used `dict()`.  When a class is called like a function, an instance is created, and the instance's `.__init__()` method is called with the arguments given to the class.  Well, calling an instance method is the same thing as calling the class method with the instance as a first argument.  Therefore, `x = dict()` is short for:

```
x = new dict instance
dict.__init__(x)
```

If you already have an instance of `dict` (or a subclass) that was not initialized, you can call `__init__()` yourself.  You *must*, however, remember to pass the instance as the first argument:

```
dict.__init__(self, pm)
```

The more common way is to use the built-in `super()`:

```
super(ProbabilityMass, self).__init__(pm)
```